# Android: Scroll down ListView, when keyboard opens

Tags: android, listview

I have the following layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="de.blabla.bla.MessageActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/mytheme_dark">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/listView2"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:divider="@null" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-50dp">

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/messageInput"
                android:background="#9f7348"
                android:layout_marginRight="65dp"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

            <Button
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Send"
                android:id="@+id/sendButton"
                android:background="@color/mytheme_color"
                android:layout_marginLeft="-65dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

It shows a Listview and a text input-field below. If I press on the text input-field, the keyboard opens and covers some listview elements. I want to scroll the listview down, when the keyboard opens. How can I do that?

**EDIT:**
When doing, what the answers say, it works except that the keyboard half overlapst the inputfield. See the pic:

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in the Activity which hosts the ListView. Also you can add it in the Manifest as well

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

Change the current XML to this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="de.freshD.crapapp.MessageActivity">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/listView2"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_above="@+id/messageInput"
    android:background="#FFF"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/messageInput"
    android:background="#9f7348"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/sendButton" />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Send"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/sendButton"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView2" />


 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: First, it seems to work. BUT, the textinput-field Element "messageInput" is half covered from the keyboard input, why that?

Comment: what is it you want to achieve here?

Comment: I think you know what I want to achieve, you already gave my an almost working answer. If I press on the "messageInput"-element, the keyboard opens and the listview is scrolled down, like I wanted (ty). BUT the textinput itself is half overlapped by the keyboard.

Comment: What do yo mean by half overlapped by the keyboard, I did not understand that

Comment: a picture of the current situation would help

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106100/discussion-between-veeresh-charantimath-and-prognewbie).

Answer (score 0):

You can also put `adjustPan` or `adjustResize` in your activity manifest:

```
<application ... >
    <activity
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" ... >
        ...
    </activity>
    ...
</application>
```

Here is some [more info](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) about this.